# Dynamically Change Embed Video URL on WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, video, youtube

My wordpress home page has an embed video from youtube, I would like to change this embed video dynamically, without needing to edit my wordpress settings.

I tried to create a custom webpage redirecting to my video, so all I would need to do e run a script to change this page's URL, but it's not working, any clue on how to fix it?

I used to following code to redirect:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eho8HDtkCiU">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "http://https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eho8HDtkCiU"
        </script>
        <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Note: don't tell people to `click` the link, just tell them that it is a link. -->
        If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href='http://https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eho8HDtkCiU'>link to example</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you say "but it's working"?

Comment: Do you think insert that page in your wordpress with an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting them to the link, why don't you download the video using a YouTube to MP4 converter online, then keep that in the FTP of the WordPress. Then, perhaps you can use the video tag to show the MP4 file.